# VSTS Windows build agent not Xamarin-enabled?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I am experimenting with VSTS and CI with Xamarin projects. In doing so I have been running an on-premise build agent on my Mac, to observe the files used and emitted during the build process (in the _work sub folder tree). I have also been running a local build agent on my PC, when building the mobile backend (to be deployed to Azure) but when I start a build for the Android project on the Windows on-prem build agent I get this message from VSTS:

```
There are agents that are capable of running the build, but they are not online. If the agent is configured to run as a service, ensure that the "VSO Agent ({agent name})" service is running.
```

I have double-checked the build agent is indeed running and connected to VSTS so my conclusion is it is incapable of running the Android build task. Indeed, if I disable that step, the build starts as expected.

So, Is the Windows version of the build agent incapable of building Xamarin projects?

[EDIT]
Some more experimenting tells me this is related to the machine and, possibly, our corporate network. On my Mac I flipped back to a non-corporate local account and joined the open "Guest" network that is not running behind a proxy. This makes the agent available as a "Xamarin capable" agent. I also successfully built both an iOS and Android project this way. But if I switch back to the corporate local account, the agent becomes "Xamarin incapable" again, even if I join the guest network. So, apparently, the agent's capabilities for building Xamarin projects can be affected by the machine's setup. I will investigate further and also bring this to Microsoft to try and figure out what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: I later tried using the on-prem Mac build agent to build the Android app but I get the exact same result. So, it appears the downloadable build agent is indeed incapable of building Android projects. Either that or I'm missing something very basic somewhere.

Comment: Did you install VS with Xamarin for your agent machines? If you installed VS with Xamarin and have Android SDK, you can use Visual Studio Build task to build your Xamarin android project. Besides, you can also use Xamarin.Android task on your mac agent.

Comment: Yes, VS/Xamarin is installed both on my PC and Mac, where I'm running y agents. However, I later found out the problem is related to how the machine is being strangled by our corporate profiles. See my edit in the original post. Thanks for your time anyway. :-)